# Why adding a criteria in for loop significantly improves the speed

Tags: java, sorting

I'm writing Shellsort in Java and found that adding a criteria in a for loop significantly improves the speed. Can someone explain why?

This is the fast code, 80ms for 10K Doubles.

```java
    public static void sort(Comparable[] a) {
        if (a.length <= 1) {
            return;
        }

        // Using 3K+1 starting from < N/3 as in the book
        int magic = 1;
        while (magic < a.length / 3) {
            magic = 3 * magic + 1;
        }

        while (magic >= 1) {
            for (int i = magic; i < a.length; i += 1) {
                if (less(a[i - magic], a[i])) {
                    // Already in good order
                    continue;
                }

                for (int j = i; j >= magic && less(a[j], a[j - magic]); j -= magic) {
                    // if (less(a[j], a[j - magic])) {
                        exch(a, j, j - magic);
                    // }
                }
            /*
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j += 1) {
                if (less(a[i], a[j])) {
                    // j is the right place
                    // Use a series of exchanges to avoid creating new arrays
                    for (int k = i; k > j; k -= 1) {
                        exch(a, k-1, k);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            */
            }
            magic /= 3;
        }
    }
```

The slow version (I'll just put the inner for loop here) which takes around 43,000ms

```java
                for (int j = i; j >= magic; j -= magic) {
                    if (less(a[j], a[j - magic])) {
                        exch(a, j, j - magic);
                    }
                }
```

Please note that the `less` function simply check whether `a[j]` is smaller than `a[j-magic]`.

From what I understand, in the fast code, we still check the `less` criteria for each loop, and if it doesn't satisfy we don't go inside the loop. In the slow version, we do go inside each loop and even `less` is not satisfied we don't do the exchange. What I don't understand is why the fast code is SO much faster? And is it the same for C++? (I could test the C++ part by myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the slow version of the loop:

```
for (int j = i; j >= magic; j -= magic) {
      if (less(a[j], a[j - magic])) {
             exch(a, j, j - magic);
      }
}
```

In this loop, we call `less` for each value of `j`, and for the values for which `less` return true, we call `exch`. This happens until `j >= magic`.

Now, let's look at the faster version:

```
for (int j = i; j >= magic && less(a[j], a[j - magic]); j -= magic) {
     exch(a, j, j - magic);
}
```

In this version, we also call `less` for each value of `j`, but for the first value of `j` it returns false, the execution exits the loop. So, in this condition after the loop exits, it is not necessary that `j < magic`. As a result, many calls to `exch` and `less` are saved here, which results in optimization.

This will be the same for every language.

Comment: Thanks @Charchit Kapoor you are absolutely right! How come I didn't realize it? I should have know it from my introductory programming course...I guess it's because I never did that in my own code.

Comment: It happens @NicholasHumphrey, we all miss these sort of points one day or the other.